# cant find <video> src (url)

Tags: javascript, python, html, apache, python-requests

I tried to download a video from [Website](http://findow.ir/academy/course/%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%84-%D8%AA%DA%A9%D9%86%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%84-%DA%A9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C%DA%A9) but after I clicked on save button it's showed
*'500' status code*
error, so I used my HTML knowledge and inspect it to found `src` and it's was regular `<video>` tag ***BUT*** it didn't have any `<source>` tag inside so it didn't have any `src`.
I tried Network inspect and found some `mp4` `GET requests` but it not a real or was something wired cause they size and content and **file extension** (it's letters instead of .mp4) :(
[image: Network inspect]
So I went to wrote it by python, but can't got response with python ***requests library*** and all of requests received 500 status_code fail (when tried to connect to mp4 file, not the web page its right) .

```
import requests

url = 'http://findow.ir/academy/playVideo/%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%84-%D8%AA%DA%A9%D9%86%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%84-%DA%A9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C%DA%A9?key=A6ovzaxPThTSp0vCC73DyTIMzIlI0C1p5RwtF3xr&course=true&type=medium'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
```

[image: Response]
So I copied and deleted all the browser headers and found the necessary headers :

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
           'Range': 'bytes=18186240-',
           'Cookie': '_hjid=c42f4ea0-1335-4aef-98d0-d41b2754c31f; _ga=GA1.2.665970563.1633193010; _gid=GA1.2.536059028.1633193010; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImJDZjRDaDMrWWRDQnFyaGdYeXZ5XC9RPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImM4bm01d3RXR21DV1wvWlplNjlTNnJcL3o3WEZDeFVVTDNaRFhIMk1DR0s5d3lLWmpxUDdzWnlrQ2pQZmJDa3pCMSIsIm1hYyI6ImVjMmM5OGZlOGQwNWQyZjRiNTZjMjgzODJjZTUyZTU4NzdlZmE2NzU1ZDQ1ZTFmMWY5NGRlN2NiZGRhYjQ1NzIifQ%3D%3D; findow_session=eyJpdiI6ImxaaGlUc3FuQzdzUDJPWElPc1Q5T2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVXdUVm1oRzJDZlk0RlFjQWJBTk8xWFVxM1RPWk9Qcm1KeEZDSjdoWjlnM3U3ZWhESlcycGVEQnpTaWZTSDFtSiIsIm1hYyI6IjMxMzY4ZGIxNzNkOGE0YTEyY2M3ZDRhMzA1OTFlMDdhZDk2MWJhZjdjZmM3YzBjOTUzMzk4YzVjMTBlMjY5ZmQifQ%3D%3D; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _gat_gtag_UA_155117102_1=1',
           }
```

and I got **206 *status-code*** :)

I realized that websites use `Video.js` to show its video file, so I'm suspicious of ***Javascript***.

Now I'm very eager to find this strange url and download it file with & without python or JS or... .

Comment: Did you try right clicking on the video and clicking "copy video address"?

Comment: You could try [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl). It should support `video.js` videos.

Comment: @Laif yes sure but it didn't work